# Python and SQL Server: How can I fill a database in the 3NF with a Python script

Tags: python, sql-server

I wrote a Python script to read data from a CSV file into a SQL Server database and everything worked when everything was read into a table.

Now I have put the database in the 3NF and I don't know exactly how to fill the database correctly.
[image]

Python Code:

```
def connection_string(driver, server_name, database_name):
    conn_string = f"""
        DRIVER={{{driver}}};
        SERVER={server_name};
        DATABASE={database_name};
        Trust_Connection=yes;        
    """
    return conn_string

sql_insert = '''
    INSERT INTO Land(ISOCode, LandName)
    VALUES (?, ?)
    INSERT INTO Infections(InfactionsAtThisDay)
    VALUES (?)
    INSERT INTO CurrentDate(DateDay)
    VALUES (?)
    INSERT INTO CovidData(LandId, CurrentDateId, InfectionsId) 
    VALUES ((select LandId from Land), (select CurrentDateId from CurrentDate), (select InfectionsId from Infections));
'''
```

CSV Data: https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/blob/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv

All tables are filled with the data except for "CovidData".

My question is what do I have to change so that "CovidData" is filled correctly?

Comment: The whole point of putting it into 3NF is that you don't necessarily have a new row in every table for every original source row. You would need to do an `INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS` on each of the parent tables, then select the ID back out

Comment: A common pattern is to create a Pandas data frame for each target table, moving most of the data manipulation into Python.  Alternatively load a single staging table in SQL Server and move most of the data manipulation to SQL Server.

Comment: CurrentDate is a table for what purpose? Why do you need LandId as PK in Land if (presumably) ISOCode or LandName is a natural key. "InfectionsAtThisDay" seems to have no real purpose as well. I can only really see two actual entities (tables) here - your covid data and the location. I suspect you don't really need a location table but it might be useful to have.